# How to pass something of type Compare_fn into sprintf() for a C program?

Tags: c, function, testing

I have the following line of code in my C program.

```
sprintf(cmd, "test mergesort %n %x %x %?", A, n, x, my_cmp);
```

`my_cmp` is of type `Compare_fn` and I need to know how to pass it into this function.  This line is used to help execute a command needed for testing purposes.

If anyone knows how to pass a variable of type `Compare_fn` into this function, it would be really helpful.

I'm not trying to print anything with my_cmp at all.  I have a function that has Compare_fn variable as a parameter and am simply executing the function in the shell.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Print the results of `my_cmp(n, x)` ?

Comment: What is `Compare_fn`? Some type of function pointer? If you want to get the name of the function pointed too by a function pointer, there's no easy way to do it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351134/how-to-get-functions-name-from-functions-pointer-in-c) for some more info.

Comment: What is compare_fn defined as?

Answer (score 2):

ISO C does not define a conversion from function pointer types to `void *`, but almost all implementations do define such a conversion (and POSIX requires it to be defined), which you can use to convert the function pointer to `void *` and print it with `%p`. If you don't want to rely on this, you can use the fact that all types in C are required to have a *representation* as an overlaid array of `unsigned char`:

```
Compare_fn fp;
unsigned char rep[sizeof fp];
memcpy(rep, &fp, sizeof rep);
for (i=0; i<sizeof rep; i++) printf("%.2x", rep[i]);
```

Obviously you could store the hex output to a string instead of stdout if you prefer, using `snprintf` or your own byte-to-hex code.