# How to get function's name from function's pointer in C for Windows XP with MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I have seen this answer [How to get function's name from function's pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351134/how-to-get-functions-name-from-functions-pointer-in-c). but this solution is for linux.

Comment: These might help you find your answer :  
[Win32 - Backtrace from C code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693192/win32-backtrace-from-c-code/5699483#5699483)   
[How can one grab a stack trace in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I found this http://ivbel.blogspot.fr/2012/02/how-to-get-functions-name-from.html

```
    res = SymGetSymFromAddr64(GetCurrentProcess(), addr, &dis64, pSym);
if (!res)
{
    /* TODO: call your trace function instead of printf */
    printf("SymGetSymFromAddr64 fails, error=%ld\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}
else
{
    strcpy(symbolName, pSym->Name);
}
```

The full code is on the link