# Determining to which function a pointer is pointing in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a pointer to function, assume any signature.
And I have 5 different functions with same signature.

At run time one of them gets assigned to the pointer, and that function is called.

Without inserting any print statement in those functions, how can I come to know the name of function which the pointer currently points to?

Comment: The name of a function is only a helper for programmers. During runtime, the program has no notion of function names (except maybe if it was compiled to add debugging symbols).

Comment: Reading [Reflection support in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353022/reflection-support-in-c) might help.

Comment: You can't, and for any purpose other than debugging you oughtn't have to.

Comment: @cad Except if you add the standard identifier `__func__` to the code, in which case the compiler will link a string literal corresponding to the function name into the program.

Comment: @Lundin: Sorry to hunt you down like this but I thought that `__func__` was a C++ thing, not a C thing. If I'm wrong though I'll be a very happy cat.

Comment: @Bathsheba It was added to C 16 years ago.

Comment: Yep, there's this new fancy C99 standard, let's party like it's 1999 :)

Comment: OP have you considered dynamic linking with dlsym, dlopen etc.? That might enable reflection-like features in the code.

Comment: @Sumit: why exactly do you ask? Please **edit your question** to explain why and improve it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get function's name from function's pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351134/how-to-get-functions-name-from-functions-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 67):

You will have to check which of your 5 functions your pointer points to:

```
if (func_ptr == my_function1) {
    puts("func_ptr points to my_function1");
} else if (func_ptr == my_function2) {
    puts("func_ptr points to my_function2");
} else if (func_ptr == my_function3) {
    puts("func_ptr points to my_function3");
} ...
```

If this is a common pattern you need, then use a table of structs instead of a function pointer:

```
typedef void (*my_func)(int);

struct Function {
    my_func func;
    const char *func_name;
};

#define FUNC_ENTRY(function) {function, #function}

const Function func_table[] = {
    FUNC_ENTRY(function1),
    FUNC_ENTRY(function2),
    FUNC_ENTRY(function3),
    FUNC_ENTRY(function4),
    FUNC_ENTRY(function5)
}

struct Function *func = &func_table[3]; //instead of func_ptr = function4;

printf("Calling function %s\n", func->func_name);
func ->func(44); //instead of func_ptr(44);
```

Comment: `func_table->func` should be `func->` to use the selected entry here `[3]` not always entry `[0]`.

Answer (score 27):

Generally, in C such things are not available to the programmer.

There might be system-specific ways of getting there by using debug symbols etc., but you probably don't want to depend on the presence of these for the program to function normally.

But, you can of course compare the value of the pointer to another value, e.g.

```
if (ptr_to_function == some_function)
    printf("Function pointer now points to some_function!\n");
```

Comment: In C, such things _are_ actually available to the programmer through the `__func__` identifier.

Comment: @Lundin But isn't that only available in the *body* of the function? The OP wants to find the name from `ptr_to_function` alone.

Comment: @Lundin, that is a preprocessor directive that gets the current name of function which has scope currently, that doesn't even remotely apply to the question.

Comment: @Sam `__func__` is available only within the function, and thus not a good answer here, but it is a normal (precisely, TP7) identifier, not a preprocessor macro like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, nor a directive like `#if`.

Answer (score 16):

The function names will not be available at runtime.

C is not a *reflective* language.

Either maintain a table of function pointers keyed by their name, or supply a mode of *calling* each function that returns the name.

Comment: *reflective* was the word I was missing. Kudos!

Comment: And thus, the answer of reflectiveness was written.

Comment: Except if you add the standard identifier `__func__` to the code, in which case the compiler will link a string literal corresponding to the function name into the program.

Answer (score 15):

The debugger could tell you that (i.e. the name of a function, given its address).

The symbol table of an unstripped [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable could also help. See [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html), [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html)

Another Linux GNU/libc specific approach could be to use at runtime the [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) function. Assuming your program is nicely and dynamically linked (e.g. with `-rdynamic`), it can find the symbol name and the shared object path given some address (of a globally named function).

Of course, if you have only five functions of a given signature, you could compare your address (to the five addresses of them).

Notice that some functions don't have any ((globally visible) names, e.g. `static` functions.

And some functions could be `dlopen`-ed and `dlsym`-ed (e.g. inside plugins). Or their code be synthetized at runtime by some JIT-ing framework (`libjit`, `gccjit`, `LLVM`, `asmjit`). And the [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) can (and does!) inline functions, clone them, [tail-call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) them, etc.... so your question might not make any sense in general...

See also [backtrace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) & Ian Taylor's [*libbacktrace*](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) inside GCC.

But in general, your quest is impossible. If you really need such reflective information in a reliable way, manage it yourself (look into [Pitrat's CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) system as an example, or somehow my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) system), perhaps by generating some code during the build.

Answer (score 13):

To know where a function pointer points is something you'll have to keep track of with your program. Most common is to declare an array of function pointers and use an int variable as index of this array.

That being said, it is nowadays also possible to tell in runtime which function that is currently executed, by using the `__func__` identifier:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef const char* func_t (void);

const char* foo (void)
{
  // do foo stuff
  return __func__;
}

const char* bar (void)
{
  // do bar stuff
  return __func__;
}

int main (void)
{
  func_t* fptr;

  fptr = foo;
  printf("%s executed\n", fptr());

  fptr = bar;
  printf("%s executed\n", fptr());

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo executed
bar executed
```

Comment: This is akin to putting a print statement inside the function. I took that restriction to mean that you can't modify the code inside the function.

Comment: This also requires that the functions return a `const char *` (or some equivalent restriction on the prototype).  This also requires you to *call* the function...

Comment: @ratchetfreak Either you need to know which function that was called, which this solves. Or you need to know which function you are calling... which doesn't make much sense. How did you end up not knowing which function you are calling? Fundamental program design solves that: as mentioned in the answer, make an array and an index variable, simple as that.

Answer (score 10):

Not at all - the symbolic name of the function disappears after compilation. Unlike a reflective language, C isn't aware of how its syntax elements were named by the programmer; especially, there's no "function lookup" by name after compilation.

You can of course have a "database" (e.g. an array) of function pointers that you can compare your current pointer to.

Comment: Except if you add the standard identifier `__func__` to the code, in which case the compiler will link a string literal corresponding to the function name into the program.

Comment: @Lundin that's only within the function, so you'd have to add code to each function to "call" it and have it return the name, or you could do some sort of hacky memory scanning to find function names. Either way, it's not going to be simple.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen It is, by design, only available from inside the function, because that's the only place where it could be of interest. To know where a function pointer points at, indeed just simply keep track of what your own code does. However, this answer is slightly inaccurate since a function lookup feature does in a way exist.

Comment: Well, the function could copy it, returning it or loading into a passed char*

Comment: @MartinJames: but if you just start modifying arguments or return types of functions, you're no longer dealing with the same functions.

Answer (score 8):

This is utterly awful and non-portable, but assuming:

1. You're on Linux or some similar, ELF-based system.
2. You're using dynamic linking.
3. The function is in a shared library or you used `-rdynamic` when linking.
4. *Probably a lot of other assumptions you shouldn't be making...*

You can obtain the name of a function by passing its address to the nonstandard [`dladdr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) function.

Answer (score 4):

1. set your linker to output a MAP file.
2. pause the program
3. inspect the address contained in the pointer.
4. look up the address in the MAP file to find out which function is being pointed to.

Comment: Indeed. Or run `nm` over a debug build binary.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a C function is an address, like any pointer. You can get the value from a debugger. You can cast the pointer to any integer type with enough bits to express it completely, and print it. Any compilation unit that can use the pointer, ie, has the function name in scope, can print the pointer values or compare them to a runtime variable, without touching anything inside the functions themselves.