# Getting the name of C file who calls a function

Tags: c, logging

I am implementing a logger in "C" and the core function is :

```
void log(Level tag, const char *message)
```

This function will be called in a client file which is different from my `log.c` file.

My question is :

How is it possible for this function to get the name of the caller  file without passing it as a parameter (like adding another `char *`)   argument  and then passing it `__FILE__` in the caller  file ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't find the file name holding the calling function from within your `log` function. (Beware: `#include <math.h>` declares a function `log()` too — with a very different signature).  You have to pass it as an argument.  Use a macro to automate that: `#define LOG(tag, msg) debug_log(__FILE__, tag, msg)` or something similar.

Comment: You should look at [`#define` macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do is rename `log()` to `debug_log()` or something so you can use `#include <math.h>` as well as the logging mechanism. Thanks,  @JonathanLeffler.

Next thing you have to do is change `debug_log` so it accepts the file name as an argument.

```
void debug_log(Level tag, const char *message, char const* filename);
```

Then, add a macro to help with using the macro `__FILE__` automatically.

```
#define LOG_MESSAGE(tag, message) debug_log((tag), (message), __FILE__)
```

Then, use the macro instead of the function in client code.

```
LOG_MESSAGE(my_tag, my_message);
```

Comment: The first thing to do is rename `log()` to `debug_log()` or something so you can use `#include <math.h>` as well as the logging mechanism :)

Comment: That sound better than re writing all the function to a macro. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Make it a macro instead, which always passes `__FILE__` to the function it calls.

That way the logger calls are cleaner-looking (you don't see the extra argument).

For example, to always add function name and line number, I use the following which also has variable arguments so you can call it like `printf()` with a format string and arguments.
This requires GCC macro features.

```
#define DBG(x, args...) ({ \
    if (debug) { \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: " x "\n", __func__, __LINE__, ##args);  \
    } \
})
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks. I think that is the best way to go.

Comment: Yeah I see but the problem is that I have a lot of line in my function so i think that the answer below is better for my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCC and you don't mind compiling with `-rdynamic`, you can use function `backtrace()` to get a backtrace, and then either `dladdr()` to find the name of the single function (the fist one in the list, returned by `backtrace()`), or `backtrace_symbols` to get symbols for all functions in stack, and use just a first one.

A bit more details here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/351980/28494

See `man` for details.