# Getting caller function name from the function address

Tags: c, u-boot

I have printed the address of the function in U-boot by adding the following print.

```
  printf("initcall: %pS \n", (char *)*init_fnc_ptr - reloc_ofs);
```

Following line printed by adding debug prints. Is there anyway to know the function name from the function address.

```
  initcall: 80809c05
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351134/how-to-get-functions-name-from-functions-pointer-in-c probably?

Comment: In U-boot we will not be having /proc/, backtrace() also not available in U-boot.

Comment: Subtract the load address and then look up the symbol table of the compiled binary

Comment: regarding the example output: "initcall: 80809c05" This is NOT the output from the posted code, because the call to `printf()` has a 'S' after the address.

Comment: The output format specifier is expecting a `void*`, not a `char*`

Comment: regarding: `printf("initcall: %pS \n", (char *)*init_fnc_ptr - reloc_ofs);`  why not simply use: `printf("initcall: %s\n", "init_fnc_ptr");` or, more generic: `printf("initcall: %s \n", __func__);`

Answer (score 0):

When building U-Boot a file u-boot.map is written. You can look up the the addresses of the functions (before relocation) there.